# Почему у класса Integer есть тип данных int, а у класса String нет?

Tags: java, дизайн-языка

Почему у класса Integer есть тип данных int, а у класса String нет какого-нибудь str или string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, Вам нужно разобраться, чем именно обусловлено существование примитивного и ссылочного типа данных. Например, вышеупомянутый  int - число в диапазоне   от -2147483648 до 2147483647, следовательно под него можно заранее выделить память в размере 32 бит и ее гарантировано хватит. Т.е. вы написали в своем коде "private int var;", переменная уже объявлена, а нужное значение в нее будет записано позже, но уже на этом этапе мы знаем, что нам хватит 32 бит и можем их выделить. А теперь возьмем String... Здесь все несколько сложнее, поскольку вы можете написать в переменную типа String свое имя, а можете всю Войну и мир. Таким образом, определить заранее (при объявлении переменной), сколько именно памяти Вам потребуется невозможно в принципе. Для решения этой проблемы и используется ссылочный тип. По сути в память записывается ссылка. Теперь Ваша переменная привязана к ссылке, а ссылка будет указывать на область памяти, которая выделится, когда это потребуется и в объемах, которые потребуются.Таким же способом можно записать другое заначение в переменную - тогда ссылка останется прежней, однако, она будет указывать на вновь выделенную достаточную по объему область памяти. Отсюда преимущества и недостатки этих типов. Примитив всегда быстрее, ведь Вы сразу знаете где хранятся Ваши данные, однако приходится заранее выделять область памяти, аэто не всегда возможно. Ссылочный тип решает последнюю проблему, но вы вынуждены обращаться к данным не на прямую, а через ссылку и это, разумеется, медленнее. 
Старался объяснить очень простым языком, посему в реальности все сложнее, но для понимания общего смысла происходящего этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: Почти любое обращение делается через ссылку. `int x=10; ++x;` Если бы не было ссылки, `++` бы не смог отработать.

Comment: а еще есть виртуальные машины, операционные системы, драйвера и т.д. если можете объяснить проще, то количество ответов не ограничено. как по мне, то для человека начинающего для общего понимания происходящего этого вполне достаточно...

Comment: спасибо, но почему тогда не сделали примитив для коротких строчных значений, я могу предположить, что строчные перемены реже используют для "войны и мир" чем для записи чего-то короткого. и из-за низкого потребления длинных строк жертвовать производительностью для коротких строк по-моему не рационально.

Comment: да, короткие строчные значения встречаются гораздо чаще и именно по такому пути решения этой проблемы пошли реляционные базы данных.  теперь вам нужно указывать длину переменной для каждой колонки, а ее превышение грозит исключением. это просто разные подходы к решению одной проблемы со своими преимуществами и недостатками.

Answer (score 2):

Примитивные типы - это оптимизация чтобы не городить объект-обёртку, по размеру превышающую само значение и не выделять под него помять в куче. А строки - и так довольно жирная штуковина с массивом внутри и их довольно затруднительно разместить в стеке. Так что абсолютно никакого смысла делать для них фиктивный примитив нет.

Answer (score 1):

**[String](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/7/api/java/lang/String.html) класс** представляет символьные строки. Все строковые литералы в программах Java, такой как "abc", реализуются как экземпляры этого класса. 
**[Integer](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/7/api/java/lang/Integer.html) класс** обертывает значение типа примитива int в объекте. Объект типа Integer содержит единственное поле, тип которого int.